# Partitioning for Windows 8 installation error

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, windows-8, partitioning

[image: Partition table]

This is my partition table. Here Windows 7 is the C:/ of windows 7 and others and softwares is E:/ and F:/ respectively. 18 GB ext4 is ubuntu 10.04 primary partition. The free 42 GB was my D:/ drive. I have deleted it for the installation of windows 8. But the setup of windows 8 says can't create a new partition and a error code while selecting new option. When I tried to create simple volume in windows 7 it tells "not enough space in disk". What is the pro

Answer (score 0):

I used EaSuS partition manager and created partition then it works

Answer (score -1):

First, your screen shot has been reduced in size to the point of illegibility, and therefore near uselessness. The one thing I can take away from it is that most of your partitions are logical partitions. If you try to create a new primary partition, this will require resizing the extended partition that holds the logical partitions, and possibly moving one or more logical partitions, depending on where the available space is.

Overall, I recommend that you try using GParted for this. It's got a better user interface, IMHO. You can also create NTFS partitions in GParted. If you intend to install Windows on such a partition, it *must* be a primary partition, so you may need to deal with those primary/extended/logical distinctions.

Comment: The screenshot is 1360x768 in size

Comment: Under both Opera and Firefox, the screen shot is reduced to 644x362, with no option to click to view it in a fuller size. That may be a function of this site's software, but it still results in an illegible screen shot. I now see that it's possible to save to disk and recover the full size, but that's a hassle. I stand by every word I wrote in my response, despite what I presume to be your downgrade of it.

Comment: @RodSmith: You can't really blame the OP for what the site does (thankfully it is not permanently resizing the image). I wish SE would provide an automatic (click to) zoom option for large images, but a suggestion on meta seems to have been left hanging for years. Still, I guess it doesn't take too much effort to right-click the image and select "View Image" in FF or its equivalent in Opera, does it?